# Fragment layout in navigation drawer Android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm new to Android application and have just started learning. I'm writing an application using Navigation drawer and fragments

It was working fine with layout but with Fragment the content is hidden inside navigation top bar

**Expected Display is like to be**

[image: expected]

**But, this is how the layout is**

[image]

**NEXT DATE** is hidden behind action bar

***Code for layout is***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.thecoders.periodtracker.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I'd suggest to try removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: There are two occurance of `fitsSystemWindows="true"`. Tried remove both but same output screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your FrameLayout.

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

and this too.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add topMargin in your `Framelayout`:

```
android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a relative layout inside the coordinator layout and add rule to your frame layout that it should be below `appBarLayout` something like below :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should wrap your framLayout inside a NestedSCrollView (not necessary though).

The trick is this line :

> app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

The CoordinatorLayout's children will behave differently if you give them a 
[Behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html).

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- Rest of the code there -->

        </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```